# Is there a hasNext() equivalent method for Strings?

Tags: java, string, methods, substring, java.util.scanner

I know about the java method has.Next() which pertains to Scanners, but is there an equivalent method that scans a string to see if it has a next byte?

I am trying to write a program that removes the last character from a string, so if there is a much easier way to achieve that I would like to know. My current idea is to keep scanning the string for how many characters it has, use that number in the subString() method, and print the original string without the last character. This has to do it regardless of the size of the string.

Comment: There is a length() method on Strings. Combine that with your substring() method idea and you have one answer.

Comment: whoops, forgot about that one! My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have access to the number of characters in the string, using `String.length()`.

If you want to extract the string up to but excluding the last character, you can simply use `substring`:

```
str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)
```

If you simply want to *print* the same string to a `PrintWriter` (like `System.out`), you don't need to extract the substring explicitly:

```
System.out.write(str, 0, str.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always iterate over the character array, but in this case you don't need to.  You already know the string's length.